# Using https throws error while getting HttpResponseMessage from HttpClient.Result

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code in which a service in the controller calls a service in another controller :

```
[Route("Employees")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TCPEmployeeAsync()   
{            
    StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder();
    uri.Append(ApiHelper.GetHost(this.Request));
    uri.Append("/HumanResources/Employees");
    uri.Append("?fields=id,fname,lname,email");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //This is where it gives error when uri contains https//
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri.ToString()).Result; 

    return response;
}
```

This was just deployed in a DMZ server, and when we use `http://localhost....`  it works just fine but when we use `https://example.domain.com/...` it gives the following exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the 
>       connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
>       established connection failed because c
>       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
>       Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState 
>       state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

What might be the problem? All my certificates are in place and up to date and also tried disabling TLS/SSL in the server, but that didn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is the same application, have you considered just returning the result of executing that action, rather than making a new request?

Comment: What IP address does "example.domain.com" (or whatever you're really using) resolve to _on that machine_? Probably it's a public IP. Are there suitable firewall rules in place to allow the traffic _out onto the internet and back in to that machine_, if so? Try e.g. `telnet example.domain.com 443" on that machine, to test.  You can achieve better performance, and avoid firewall issues, by having a local DNS (or just the hosts file if you have to) resolve that alias to the internal IP of that machine instead.